# Who are the miners?

Tags: blockchain, blocks

In blockchain there are some miners who calculate hash and get reward but my question is who are the miners or how can I be a miner (assume). If there are then  I can be connected to a miner?

I am very new in learning blockchain. This may be a very silly/irrelevant question but my curious mind wants to know.

Comment: You probably mean *miner*

Answer (score 1):

In blockchain to solve byzantium problem consensus mechanism is done by proof of work where miner nodes waste some computational power of their CPU/GPU to calculate valid hash and hence confirm the block/transaction.
Miner can be one with his/her laptop/CPU installed with ethereum client and registered as Miner node.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, miner is a someone who investing computation power to generate shares and help finding blocks.
To became miner, you need to get a good hardware then connect to the pool using miner program.